# SebastianM/angular2-google-maps not responsive

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I would like to have my marker/markers appear on the viewport when my screen size decreases, but the angular2-google-maps hides the marker/markers when i decrease the screen dimensions and i have to scroll to view the markers

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
<sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

I have my lat,lng and zoom in my component class defined accordingly, is it possible to make this map responsive? so that on my screen i don't need to drag the map to see the marker, if it is, can i do it for multiple markers, in such a way that i see all the markers on a smaller screen, i appreciate any help.